# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How does Walter White make pure crystal meth using a non-stereospecific reaction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/how-does-walter-white-make-pure-crystal-meth-using-a-non-stereospecific-reaction)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Plutonium having more oxidation states than samarium?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7704/plutonium-having-more-oxidation-states-than-samarium)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Electrochemical cell-SRP value](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/electrochemical-cell-srp-value)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Comparing acidities of substituted and aromatic carboxylic acids](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7591/comparing-acidity-of-substituted-and-aromatic-carboxylic-acid)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why is water wet and fire hot?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/why-is-water-wet-and-fire-hot)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Reaction of Haloalkane with Diphenyl Sulfide in presence of AgBF4](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/reaction-of-haloalkane-with-diphenyl-sulfide-in-presence-of-agbf4)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the correct form for the acid-base equilibrium constant potential: pK_a or pK_A?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/what-is-the-correct-form-for-the-acid-base-equilibrium-constant-potential-pk-a)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Rapidly cooling Aluminum vapour to solid state?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/rapidly-cooling-aluminum-vapour-to-solid-state)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Hybridisation of Mn in potassium permanganate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7486/potassium-permanganate-hybridisation)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does chelation take ions out of solution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/does-chelation-take-ions-out-of-solution)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 7)

---